# Frontend for making website like Product Hunt/ Reddit

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a web app which is kinda like Product Hunt. I got the back-end API working, and for the front-end I have angular js working. Thing is I don't have any experience with the look and feel of the site. Should I go about creating the css from scratch or look for an open source template online? If I go the template way, can anyone point me to a reddit/product hunt type template? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a personal decision, but I would suggest to go with creating it on your own with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) CSS/JS. You tagged Bootstrap in the question, so I'm assuming you have a general understanding of what it is.

Because of how popular it is, it's a great skill to learn regardless and will be useful for any web development project now and in the forseeable future. The other plus is that the learning curve isn't as steep as other parts of web development.

Comment: Bootstrap is great. My favorite is Semantic-UI. IMO it looks better and has better functionality than Bootstrap. Like awwester said, it is personal preference.